# PHP Script not Working: error on line 1 column 538

Tags: php, mysql, xml, web, xml-parsing

I have no idea of what is going wrong, i was using this same script to get another XML and it was working just fine.
This is the script:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"LATIN-1\"?>";
echo "<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">";
echo "<plist version=\"1.0\">";

function getXML($sql="SELECT IDCargo FROM database.table"){

    $conn   = mysql_connect ("myserverurl.com", "user", "psw");
    $db     = mysql_select_db("database");
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
    $column = "";
    echo "<array>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $column .= "<dict>";
        foreach ($row as $key => $value){
            $column .= "<key>$key</key>";
            $column .= "<string>$value</string>";
        }
        $column .= "</dict>";
    }

    echo $column;
    echo "</array>";
    echo "</plist>";
}
getXML("SELECT IDCargo as ID_CARGO, SequencialDoCandidato as NUMERO_SEQ_CANDIDATO, NomeDoCandidato AS NOME_CANDIDATO, NumeroDoCandidato as NUMERO_CANDIDATO, NomeDoPartido AS SIGLA_PARTIDO, Estado as SIGLA_ESTADO,IDUnidadeEleitoral AS ID_CIDADE_CANDIDATO, UnidadeEleitoral AS CIDADE_CANDIDATO FROM database.table");
mysql_close();
?>
```

It brings this error:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 538: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

ID_CARGO11NUMERO_SEQ_CANDIDATO10000002965NOME_CANDIDATOAGRECINO DE SOUSANUMERO_CANDIDATO13SIGLA_PARTIDOPTSIGLA_ESTADOACID_CIDADE_CANDIDATO1120CIDADE_CANDIDATO
```

Can anyone see anything? Give me some help here, please.
I got the script from one that was working just fine.

Comment: Could it be that one of your $key or $value contains a character that has special meaning for XML like <, > or &? Make sure to escape those.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your code, I can see :

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"LATIN-1\"?>";
```

So I guess you want to output LATIN-1 charset. You need to specify this charset everywhere :

1/ You can try to specify the encoding on the http header :

```
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

2/ And you can also set the charset on the DB client :

```
mysql_set_charset('latin1', $db);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output most likely contains a character or characters in an encoding not supported in the default encoding.

Either update the encoding you use, or escape any characters that does not fit the encoding. The `htmlentities` php function would be a good start.